# How to prevent add related entity when add an entity?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

I have two Entities : Category and Product with a many to many relationship.
How can I prevent the UI Programmer to add  a Category when he wants to add a Product? In fact I want the UI programmmer to only add Products and set predefined Categories and not to be able to add new Categories for the Product.

Answer (score 0):

You must code the logic in your layer exposed to UI programmer and ensure that only product is created. That means you must wrap EF completely in your layer and do not expose it to upper layers. If you expose EF context to upper layer you are giving it all permissions.

Comment: thanks  Ladislav Mrnka. you mean I must define business entity? if yes, how can I use Poco entity relation benefits?

Comment: @mehranasghari Just wrap the Product (POCO) Entity in a Product Class on the Bussinesslayer that exposes only the Properties en Methods you want the UI Programmer to use. Inside the Bussiness layer class you can then modify the properties of the wrapped Entity Product that is still tracked by the context.